# Is there a word for over-thinking actions that should simply be done?

Tags: single-word-requests

I remember a scene from a Stallone-movie where Stallone and his opponents train for a fight. The opponent uses "scientific methods", a "well though out plan" and so on, and stallone just works out more and more, and finally wins.

Also, there's a quote in german: "Das Runde muss ins Eckige" (the round thing must go into the cornered thing), about soccer, making fun of too complex plans of playing, instead of just concentrating on the basic goal of putting the ball into the goal.

Is there a word for this overthinking-attitude instead of "just doing it" in english?

Comment: "Over-thinking it' is already a pretty good choice.

Comment: I, too, don't understand what's wrong with [*overthinking*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overthinking).

Comment: You're overthinking this by not just going with "overthinking". Anyway, not a single word, but "analysis paralysis" may apply.

Answer (score 1):

**Overthinking** is a pretty good choice already:

> think about (something) too much or for too long.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/overthink)

However, if you want to be fancy, you could use Shakespeare:

> **Letting 'I dare not' wait upon 'I would'** (like the cat i' the adage)

Is a famous quote by Lady Macbeth when she was trying to get her husband to kill the king.

[Macbeth](https://www.sparknotes.com/nofear/shakespeare/macbeth/page_42) Act I Scene VII.